# How well do Python machine learning algorithms scale?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

How well do Python machine learning algorithms scale for web applications?

So far, I am impressed with the [Mahout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Mahout) library but as a Python programmer I was hoping there are also libraries catered towards scaling really well.

Comment: I have also found Crab which is a python recommendation library positioned as mahout alternative for python developers according to the slides on slideshare.

Comment: The general rule is that the algorithms are more relevant to scaling than the language or platform - and in any case, performance critical sections (as Raymond points out) might be coded using C or C++, or using NumPy (which itself uses either C or C++ for performance) or whatever. I would guess you'd pay a fixed performance penalty for using Python, and that penalty would be small - but the only way to be sure is to test the particular library you're interested in with various differently scaled examples.

Comment: FWIW, I use some ID3-like code in one of my programs. It's naively coded so it runs extremely slowly - even though it's written in C++ - due to failing to manage a combinatorial explosion. As it only ever has to deal with very small cases, I don't much care - but it still illustrates the fact that the algorithm can be much more significant than the language or platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure Python code tends to run slower than compiled languages.  Instead, it favors rapid development.

When Python coders need speed-ups, they tend to use C/C++ libraries with Python wrappers, use [NumPy](https://numpy.org/), run [pypy](https://www.pypy.org/), or construct fast extensions using [Cython](https://cython.org/).

These alternatives could each be applied to a machine learning application.  A couple tools that are popular (and seem to scale well) are [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/) and [PyML](https://pyml.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: would running python code on hadoop help or running Hadoop/Pig with UDF's in python help?

Comment: scikit-learn scales pretty well (with the help of numpy and scipy) and is popular.

Comment: @RubyGladiator Hadoop is a great tool for scaling.  Some ML algorithms are easily partitioned into subproblems but others may be a more difficult fit.  The correct answer to your question really depends on the details of the specific application.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger yes i noticed that, the reason why i asked this question to begin with is because i was playing around with the mahout library built on top of hadoop which is built for scalability but it  requires java, so i was looking for an equivelant in python, i guess i would have to use hadoop streaming and write out my python algorithms in a map-reduce fashion. I did find a good python recommendation engine built for scalability called CRAB.